# Dual boot date and time changes

Tags: boot, time, date

I have a problem that dual boot system did not set a date and time as usual when I set that date and time every time I login.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me... Ubuntu always was okay and Windows kept getting the time wrong:

https://superuser.com/a/613861/477739

`RealTimeIsUniversal` registry key still works in Windows 8 and 10! Just tested it by myself. The instructions to use this method are explained lot of times everywhere, for example in this answer.

I will replicate the answer here:

`Win`+`S`, `regedit`, `Enter`.

Navigate to the key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation.
```

Create new DWORD (32-bit) Value, name it RealTimeIsUniversal.
Set its value to 1.

After this is done, just reboot your machine. After it is up and running again, let Windows set time automatically (click on the current time in tray, Date and Time Settings > Set Time Automatically), this time it will not mess with it.